# load a lua code from the command line

Tags: command-line, lua

Hey guys how to load lua cod from the command line, or lua command line??
thank you

Answer (score 3):

Assuming a file `x.lua` in the current directory, try `lua x.lua` or `dofile"x.lua"`from the Lua prompt.

Comment: And you can use `lua -i x.lua` if you would want to access the interactive interpreter after executing the file (for example for debugging)

Comment: thanks one more question if i need to load call a function when i load the code, how I can do it for example i have function called newMessage(msg) {} am i able to make the class take arguments or there is a way to call the function. thank you again

Comment: @jprbest: if the answer you got is correct, accept it. Then create another separate question if you need to.

Answer (score 3):

This might not be what you were asking but seems relevant to the question. 
If you want to run simple code straight from command line you can do something like that:

```
 lua -e "function hw(name) return 'hello world ' .. name end; print(hw('of sorrow'))"
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for but had no idea how to search for it.